# Looping Through Columns To Remove NA's

Tags: r

I am trying to transform column data to numeric and round my numbers for each column in my data frame. I can do this manually for each column which I originally did. But now I am wondering how I could loop through my data's column so I don't have to do it manually in the future.

An example line of manually doing it is:

```
data$`Impacts` <- round(as.numeric(data$`Impacts`),2)
```

But for implementing the for loop, I have tried the following code:

```
data <- import(from desktop/wherever/etc.)
i <- 9
for (i in data) {
 data[c(i)] <- round(as.numeric(data[c(i)]),2)
 i <- i + 1
}
```

And this returns an error of:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, c(i)) : undefined columns selected
```

I tried to edit my for loop my replacing `data[c(i)]` with `data[,c(i)]` and `data$[,c(i)]` but neither of those fixed it.

I would have thought that the columns were defined as I go through the data starting at column 9 and increment through each column with `i + 1`

Am I missing something obvious? Thanks

Comment: Here, `i` is a whole column, a vector of something. I think you were trying to use `for (i in seq_len(ncol(data)))` or similar (but `lapply` is likely better, see Ronak's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lapply` :

```
data[] <- lapply(data, function(x) round(as.numeric(x),2))
```

Or using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%  summarise_all(~round(as.numeric(.), 2))
```

---

If you want to round only specific columns say `1:3`, you can do

```
data[1:3] <- lapply(data[1:3], function(x) round(as.numeric(x),2))
```

and

```
data %>% summarise_at(1:3, ~round(as.numeric(.), 2))
```

Comment: Thinking back to this reply, I am just wondering what the variable ```x``` does in the equation - how does it know what to do with ```x``` since I don't have anything named that?

Comment: @samrizz4 `function(x)` is known as an anonymous function since this function does not have a name. When we use `lapply` it passes each column as vector to anonymous function which is represented with `x`. So for first iteration first column is `x`, for second iteration second column is `x` and so on.